# Xamarin.Forms NavBar in iOS shows last page's title

Tags: xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, xamarin.forms

Whenever I navigate to a page, NavBar title shows two texts. One on back button, the other is my page title.

It's OK if the back button shows "back" as text, but it's showing title of previous page. How do I get rid of it? (would prefer to get no text at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the static method SetBackButtonTitle()

```
NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(Page, string)
```

**You need to call this when Page A loads**. Then when you push Page B, B's back button will show the modified text for navigating back to page A.

Comment: You need to call this when page A loads.  Then when you push page B, B's back button will show the modified text for navigating back to page A.